# Test if set is a subset, considering the number (multiplicity) of each element in the set

Tags: python, set, subset, multiset, multiplicity

I know I can test if set1 is a subset of set2 with:

```
{'a','b','c'} <= {'a','b','c','d','e'} # True
```

But the following is also True:

```
{'a','a','b','c'} <= {'a','b','c','d','e'} # True
```

How do I have it consider the number of times an element in the set occurs so that:

```
{'a','b','c'}     <= {'a','b','c','d','e'}      # True
{'a','a','b','c'} <= {'a','b','c','d','e'}      # False since 'a' is in set1 twice but set2 only once
{'a','a','b','c'} <= {'a','a','b','c','d','e'}  # True because both sets have two 'a' elements
```

I know I could do something like:

```
A, B, C = ['a','a','b','c'], ['a','b','c','d','e'], ['a','a','b','c','d','e']
all([A.count(i) == B.count(i) for i in A]) # False
all([A.count(i) == C.count(i) for i in A]) # True
```

But I was wondering if there was something more succinct like `set(A).issubset(B,count=True)` or a way to stay from list comprehensions. Thanks!

Comment: `{'a','a','b','c'}` is *exactly the same* as `{'a','b','c'}`. That is the point of sets.

Comment: In Python, set cannot have duplicate items. You may wan;t to use [collection.Counter](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) which can be thought as a multiset

Comment: Were you looking for a multi-set instead? Then use [`collections.Counter()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter).

Comment: Counter doesn't do it since `Counter('aabc') <= Counter('aaabcd')` gives True but so does `Counter('abce') <= Counter('aabcd')`. There is clearly no 'e' in the second string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @DSM deleted his  solution , I will take the opportunity to provide a prototype based on which you can expand

```
>>> class Multi_set(Counter):
    def __le__(self, rhs):
        return all(v == rhs[k] for k,v in self.items())


>>> Multi_set(['a','b','c']) <= Multi_set(['a','b','c','d','e'])
True
>>> Multi_set(['a','a','b','c']) <= Multi_set(['a','b','c','d','e'])
False
>>> Multi_set(['a','a','b','c']) <= Multi_set(['a','a','b','c','d','e'])
True
>>>
```

Comment: `==` does not seem to match `__le__`?

Comment: In my opinion there should be `<=` instead of `==`.

Comment: This isn't multiset `<=`. That would be `all(v <= rhs[k] for k,v in self.items())`.

Answer (score 13):

Since Python 3.10, "[Counters support rich comparison operators for equality, subset, and superset](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter)":

```
def issubset(X, Y):
    return Counter(X) <= Counter(Y)
```

Old: As stated in the comments, a possible solution using [`Counter`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
from collections import Counter

def issubset(X, Y):
    return len(Counter(X)-Counter(Y)) == 0
```

Comment: This is the best answer. It's simple and doesn't require the creation of a second class.

Answer (score 3):

The short answer to your question is there is no set operation that does this, because the [definition of a set](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_%28computer_science%29) does not provide those operations.  IE defining the functionality you're looking for would make the data type not a set.

Sets by definition have unique, unordered, members:

```
>>> print {'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'}
set(['a', 'c', 'b'])
>>> {'a', 'a', 'b', 'c'} == {'a', 'b', 'c'}
True
```

Comment: So then if I was to test the characters in a string instead, is there a way to test membership of each string1 character in string2 taking into account the number of times it occurs? Is there an escape from list comprehensions here?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "taking into account the number of times it occurs".  Do you mean if 'a' occurs x times in string1, then 'a' should occur > x times in string2?  And list comprehensions are a critical part of the Python language.  Embrace them :)  (You can start by writing them as a for loop if you do not understand them)

Answer (score 1):

Combining previous answers gives a solution which is as clean and fast as possible:

```
def issubset(X, Y):
    return all(v <= Y[k] for k, v in X.items())
```

- No instances created instead of 3 in @A.Rodas version (both arguments must already be of type Counter, since this is the Pythonic way to handle multisets).
- Early return (short-circuit) as soon as predicate is falsified.

Answer (score 0):

For those that are interested in the usual notion of multiset inclusion, the easiest way to test for multiset inclusion is to use intersection of multisets:

```
from collections import Counter

def issubset(X, Y):
    return X & Y == X

issubset(Counter("ab"), Counter("aab"))  # returns True
issubset(Counter("abc"), Counter("aab")) # returns False
```

This is a standard idea used in [idempotent semirings](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiring#Theory).