# Check if a word can be made from a group of letters (considering the no. of times the letters can be used)?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, subset, multiset

I'm doing a text twist program, and I'm having a problem checking whether a word can be created out of the given group of letters. It's very easy if there are no repeating letters, but how do I do it if a user inputs a word which has repeating letters? I used tuple but it does not work if the letters repeat.

To make it clearer, I'm providing this example:

Say your group of letters is `(d,n,a,e,l,i)` and the user inputs the word `need`. We can see that the letter `e` was used here twice, but since the code (using tuple) that I made just checks if a list is a subset of a list, it counts `need` as a correct answer when it is not. How do I fix it?

Comment: Please provide examples of what you have already tried.

Comment: You'll need to check both that the necessary words are in your group, and that you have enough occurrences of each letter.

Comment: post some more valid and invalid examples.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post the contents of your program. We can't help you if we don't know what you are doing.

Comment: It's an interesting question although the OP hasn't posted any code attempt of their own. But I can see how they could be stumped.

Comment: Here's a related question based on the information provided thus far: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15208369/test-if-set-is-a-subset-considering-the-number-of-each-element-in-the-set

Comment: @sgallen: True, but a) the wording of this question is more applied and infinitely more likely to be found by newbies and b) that question references 'multiplicity of an element in a set', which really means it needs to be tagged [tag:multiset]

Answer (score 2):

One way, using `collections.Counter`:

```
from collections import Counter
bag = Counter('dnaeli')
>>> Counter({'a': 1, 'e': 1, 'd': 1, 'i': 1, 'l': 1, 'n': 1})

bag.subtract(Counter('need'))
>>> Counter({'a': 1, 'i': 1, 'l': 1, 'd': 0, 'n': 0, 'e': -1})

if all(v >= 0 for v in bag.values()):
    print 'Word is contained'

# or as a three-line function:
def is_contained(a, b):
    """Test if all the letters of word a are contained in word b"""
    letters = Counter(b)
    letters.subtract(Counter(a))
    return all(v >= 0 for v in letters.values())
```

Note: `Counter.subtract()` is different to the `-` operation i.e. `Counter.__sub__()`. `Counter.subtract()` will also propagate negative (and zero) counts, which is what you need to check [¹].

([¹] @StefanPochmann's approach subtracts the letters from the candidate word; mine does the reverse. In SP's case positive leftover counts are bad; in mine negative are bad. So his approach doesn't need to care about negative or zero counts but mine does. His is less complex hence better.)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, sets don't work, but multisets do. `Counter` can be used for this.

```
letters = 'dnaeli'
words = 'line', 'linda', 'need', 'den', 'x'

from collections import Counter
for word in words:
    if not Counter(word) - Counter(letters):
        print(word)
```

Prints:

```
line
linda
den
```

Alternatively:

```
for word in words:
    if all(letters.count(c) >= word.count(c) for c in word):
        print(word)
```

This would be slow if both your letter set were very large and your words were very long, but "normal usage" it's alright.

Comment: Note: `Counter.subtract()` is different to the `-` operation i.e. `Counter.__sub__()`. `Counter.subtract()` will also propagate negative and zero counts

Comment: Well I'm not using `subtract`, so I don't understand why you're saying that.

Comment: Hmm. Your approach subtracts the letters from the candidate word; mine does the reverse. In your case positive leftover counts are bad; in mine negative are bad. So yeah, your approach doesn't need to care about negative or zero  counts but mine does. Interesting.

Comment: To be honest I didn't know what `subtract` does; I'm not sure I ever used it. Or maybe I did and then didn't like it and never looked back :-)

Comment: Me neither :-) I only knew that the builtin set operations necessarily needed to act 'different' on `Counters` to get the 'right' result. Well now we know.

Answer (score 0):

You could just try removing each letter from the allowed list until you either finish or something goes wrong (meaning you can't construct that word):

```
def TestInput(user_input_string, avia_letters_list):
    for each_letter in user_input_string:
        try:
            avia_letters_list.remove(each_letter)
        except ValueError:
            return 'sorry "%s" can not be constructed' % user_input_string  
    return 'good job, "%s" can be constructed' % user_input_string

usable_letters = ['d', 'n', 'a', 'e', 'l', 'i']

print TestInput('need', usable_letters[:])
print TestInput('lid', usable_letters[:])
print TestInput('nail', usable_letters[:])
```

Output:

```
sorry "need" can not be constructed
good job, "lid" can be constructed
good job, "nail" can be constructed
```